# Why pushing to a ViewController displays it as popup?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have been trying to figure this for a while now. When I'm pushing to a ViewController it displays it as a popup instead of the fullscreen.

I have UINavigationViewController embedded in MainPageViewController. Inside MainPageViewController, I have a "Sign in" button that once clicked it should display the HomePageViewController. The question is why it is displayed as a popup instead of fullscreen?

Below is the code that I'm using to push to the HomePageViewController, inside the Sign In button action method:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        let destinationNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationViewController") as! UINavigationController
```

Comment: you have to give viewcontroller presentation as Full Screen.

Comment: @ArunPrasath thanks!! it's working now 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to give ViewController Presentation as a Full Screen**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it by code, you can set presentation and transition style like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
destinationViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
```

And then push from your navigation controller